Unexpected behavior with tax_query in woocommerce pre_get_posts
This is a pretty simple and infuriating question. Can anyone help me understand why the tax_query fields below end up with different results? As far as I can tell, the only difference is the AND relation (which should not be necessary but doesn't hurt) in the second tax_query. Anyone? I saw this post which may be having the same problem, but the answer didn't do the trick.
(To be specific, these are the var_export results of query->get('tax_query') in pre_get_posts.)
No products returned (incorrect result):
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'terms' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Gift Cards',
    ),
    'field' => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
    'terms' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Construction:knit',
    ),
    'field' => 'slug',
  ),
)

Three products returned (the correct result):
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'terms' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Gift Cards',
    ),
    'field' => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'relation' => 'AND',
    0 => 
    array (
      'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
      'terms' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Construction:knit',
      ),
      'field' => 'slug',
    ),
  ),
)

***UPDATE AND MORE INFORMATION ***
The pre_get_posts hook is below. I am including it because something else is going on. These var_exports are being written from two different places in the function (I have commented where below). When I modified the first location to include the AND relation, the same behavior still happened. So it isn't the structure of the tax_query.
function map_my_filter($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() || ($query->get('post_type')!='product')) return;

//We have a custom query_var called my_filters which returns an array of tags for filtering
    $my_filters = $query->get('my_filters') ?: array();
    $tax_query = $query->get('tax_query') ?: array();
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'terms' => array('Gift Cards'),
        'field' => 'slug',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    );
    if ($query->get('s', null)!=null) {
        $alltags = get_terms([
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'name__like' => ':',
            'fields' => 'names',
        ]);
        $searchedtags = array_values(preg_grep('/.*:.*' . $query->get('s') . '.*/', $alltags));
//This regex is to search within tags: It correctly returns the tag 'Construction:knit' for the search term knit. But the tax_query doesn't work for some reason.

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'terms' => $searchedtags,
            'field' => 'slug',
        );
    }
    $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
// Here is where the first incorrect $query->get('tax_query') var_export was written

    if (count($my_filters) == 0) return;

    $product_tags_by_category = array();
    foreach ($my_filters as $tag) {
        $keyvalue = explode(':', $tag);
        if (count($keyvalue) == 2) {
            if (!array_key_exists($keyvalue[0], $product_tags_by_category))
                $product_tags_by_category[$keyvalue[0]] = array();
            $product_tags_by_category[$keyvalue[0]][] = $tag;
        }
    }

    $new_tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND', );
    foreach (array_keys($product_tags_by_category) as $key) {
        $new_tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'terms' => $product_tags_by_category[$key],
            'field' => 'slug',
        );
    }
//When a user filters all products by the tag 'Construction:knit' in the UI, this adds the term 'Construction:knit' to the tax_query. Here, it works correctly.

    $tax_query = $query->get('tax_query') ?: array();
    $tax_query[] = $new_tax_query;

    $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
//Here is where the second correct var_export was written
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'map_my_filter', 99, 1);

